# Is it possible that the inference time is large while number of parameters and flops are low in pytorch?

Tags: time, pytorch, time-complexity, flops

I calculated flops of network using *Pytorch*.
I used the function '*profile*' in '*thop*' library.

In my experiment. **My network** showed that

**Flops : 619.038M
Parameters : 4.191M
Inference time : 25.911**

Unlike my experiment, I would check the flops and parameters with **ResNet50** which showed that

**Flops : 1.315G
Parameters: 26.596M
Inference time : 8.553545**

Is is possible that the inference time is large while flops are low?
Or are there flops that the 'profile' function can't measure some functions?
However, Similar results came out using the '*FlopCountAnalysis* in *fvcore.nn*' and '*get_model_complexity_info* in *ptflops*'

Here is the code that I measured the inference time using Pytorch.

```
model.eval()
model.cuda()

dummy_input = torch.randn(1,3,32,32).cuda()

#flops = FlopCountAnalysis(model, dummy_input)
#print(flop_count_table(flops))
#print(flops.total())

macs, params = profile(model, inputs=(dummy_input,))
macs, params = clever_format([macs, params], "%.3f")
print('Flops:',macs)
print('Parameters:',params)

starter, ender = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True), 
torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)

repetitions = 300
timings=np.zeros((repetitions,1))

for _ in range(10):
    _ = model(dummy_input)

# MEASURE PERFORMANCE
with torch.no_grad():
    for rep in range(repetitions):
        starter.record()
        _ = model(dummy_input)
        ender.record()
        # WAIT FOR GPU SYNC
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        curr_time = starter.elapsed_time(ender)
        timings[rep] = curr_time

print('time(s) :',np.average(timings))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely normal situation. The thing is FLOPS (or MACs) are theoretical measures that may be useful when you want to disregard some hardware/software optimizations that leads to the fact that different operations will work faster/slower on different hardware.

For example in the case of neural networks the different architectures will have different CPU/GPU utilization. Let's consider two simple architectures with almost **same** number of parameters / FLOPs:

1. Deep network:

```py
layers = [nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3)]
for _ in range(12):
    layers.extend([nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, padding=1)])
deep_model = nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

2. Wide network
   `wide_model = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3, 1024, 3))`

Modern GPUs allows you to parallelize a large number of simple operations.
But when you have deep network you need to know outputs of layer[i] to compute the outputs of layer[i+1]. So it became **blocking** factor that reduces utilization of your hardware.

Complete example:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
from thop import clever_format, profile
from torch import nn


def measure(model, name):
    model.eval()
    model.cuda()

    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 64, 64).cuda()

    macs, params = profile(model, inputs=(dummy_input,), verbose=0)
    macs, params = clever_format([macs, params], "%.3f")
    print("<" * 50, name)
    print("Flops:", macs)
    print("Parameters:", params)

    starter, ender = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True), torch.cuda.Event(
        enable_timing=True
    )

    repetitions = 300
    timings = np.zeros((repetitions, 1))

    for _ in range(10):
        _ = model(dummy_input)

    # MEASURE PERFORMANCE
    with torch.no_grad():
        for rep in range(repetitions):
            starter.record()
            _ = model(dummy_input)
            ender.record()
            # WAIT FOR GPU SYNC
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
            curr_time = starter.elapsed_time(ender)
            timings[rep] = curr_time

    print("time(ms) :", np.average(timings))


layers = [nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3)]
for _ in range(12):
    layers.extend([nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, padding=1)])
deep_model = nn.Sequential(*layers)
measure(deep_model, "My deep model")

wide_model = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3, 1024, 3))
measure(wide_model, "My wide model")
```

Results:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< My deep model
Flops: 107.940M
Parameters: 28.288K
time(ms) : 0.6160109861691793
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< My wide model
Flops: 106.279M
Parameters: 28.672K
time(ms) : 0.1514971748739481
```

As you can see the models have similar number of parameters/flops but computing time is 4x large for the deep network.

It is just a one of possible reason why the inference time is large when number of parameters and flops are low. You may need to take into account other underlying hardware/software optimizations.

Comment: The time here is in ms not in seconds. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.Event.html#torch.cuda.Event.elapsed_time

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I've just copied the code from the question without checking it.

Comment: could you answer this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748248/what-should-i-consider-as-the-model-inference-time-from-the-results-i-have-her